# Problem visiting a website

Tags: website

I am a new user and I just start to use Tor.

I am trying to visit the website bet365 dt com, but when i click on sport i can't see the full content.

May missing some script or I don't know.

Is here someone could help me please.

Thank you!

P.S. I think I should install and enable flash, but i read for the privacy is better not do that on tor. So may there is any other way to fix it?

Comment: well... the solution for flash would be in the scope of the wesite-provider and finally not use flash anymore. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in NoScript addon which is installed in TOR Browser. You can temporary enable Java Script in the site in order to use the full features of the site.

In the following picture, I've marked the place you should click for granting temporary permissions for Java Script.

[image: Enablling No Script]

About Flash player, I do not suggest to use it, because it sends its traffic outside the TOR network. If you really need it, use something like Proxifier to tunnel all the TCP traffic of the computer through TOR network, and block all the UDP packets for flash player, since TOR does not accept UDP packages (except for DNS).